# Phrase to express something has had a great impact despite a negligible popularity?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, phrases, alternatives

Can you please suggest me an alternative phrase to the highlighted one that would express "when you take in account the very insignificant popular knowledge it receives"?

> The Effective Altruism movement has had a crazy impact *for the little
> it is known*.

Or would my sentence make sense the way I constructed it? Thanks!

Comment: If it had a great impact, it would be important/popular/noticeable, wouldn't it? If it went unnoticeable, its impact might be not *that* significant (and thus negligible)

Comment: as if the movement had potentially impactful ideas which were misunderstood/badly expressed

Answer (score 2):

What you've written conveys your meaning. I don't think you need the particular phrase you ask for. I might say it a little differently, perhaps

> The Effective Altruism movement has had substantial impact even
> though it is little known.

I hope your surrounding text  describes how that impact came about, given that the movement is unknown. What was the indirect mechanism?

I would avoid "crazy" unless you have some particular need for the connotations.